# Why this suggested edit was rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054441/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-bar-in-scroll-bar) question. Two users responded and one of them posted so close solution. But for a silly thing, his solution did not worked. I discussed it with him in the comment and he told me the update in the comment.

I accepted the answer as it is worked and also edited the answer as the author did not update it. But unfortunately, [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9203707) was rejected by the reviewers. Why?

I mentioned in the "Edit Summary" that **Edit is according to author's comment and I got it worked**. The reviewers should check the comments, isn't it?

#### Update:

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9205473) again and this time it got approved in one chance!

Comment: Your edit-comment is bad, though should have been a sufficient hint to the reviewers anyway. "Added authors correction from comments" would be better.

Comment: People saw code changes and freaked.  Most likely scenario here.

Comment: @Deduplicator The comment seems fine to me, the meaning is clear, and we can't expect everyone on an international website to speak flawless English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your edit looks fine to me. Although it would have been better for the author of the question to edit it in by themselves, I don't think your edit should have been rejected.

It does, after all, increase the quality of the answer (by making it completely correct).

I approved the edit, and now it only needs one more approval to go through.